# Change F key behavior on Apple keyboard

Tags: keyboard, apple

Pressing an <kbd>F</kbd> key on an Apple keyboard is taken as a special keypress (pause/play, skip track, etc.). To get it to be an actual <kbd>F</kbd> key press, you have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> and press the key.  I want to reverse this behaviour.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [Ubuntu Documentation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard)